# On-topic? Newly purchased equipment possibly defective

Tags: discussion

I just bought a new piece of equipment and based on its behavior it might be defective.  I'd like to ask if others with the same item see the same behavior.

My first thought is that such a question is too specific for photo.se.

Then I consider that this might be a design problem and others contemplating the same purchase may find significant value in the question and answer(s).

So what does the community think? On- or off-topic?

Comment: If you avoid making the question too specific to the exact piece of equipment you are using, the question should be fine. Describe the behavior you are experiencing in the general use case, and you should be able to get an answer that is helpful in a more general and more broadly helpful to the community at large.

Comment: I see. In this case if I were on the other side I'd want the know the specific manufacturer and model, so if I were considering the same purchase I could factor in the OP's experience and the experiences of the answerers.  The value of the question is limited to a specific item, but could have enough value to be on-topic.  Your response seems to indicate it might not be, which is why I'd like to get more discussion.

Comment: The problem with being highly specific is the questions and answers have a limited usefulness, both to the broader community at large, as well as in terms of longevity. That isn't to say you shouldn't mention the model...but if you can ask the question in a more general manner, it increases the potential usefulness of the question and the answers.

Answer (score 1):

[There](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/72651/my-lenss-focus-ring-can-be-twisted-past-infinity-and-the-close-focus-stops-with) [are](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/19063/what-is-causing-this-white-spot-in-every-photo-with-my-d90/19067#19067) [similar](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/24598/is-my-canon-ef-s-15-85mm-is-usm-lens-defective-or-par-for-course) questions. Go ahead. Include sample pictures showing the issue (if you can) and write what behavior you expected.

Comment: And please please don't title your question with a generic phrase like "Is my camera defective?"  — name the specific behavior.